# How to put script in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var txt = '{"name":"John", "city":"New York"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How to put the script in another file named "myscript.js" and connect to html page?
I want to do that because i want to link the script to multiple html pages and sometimes i need to change var txt = '{"name":"John", "city":"New York"}'

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything between the script tags in a text file and save it as myscript.js

then replace your script tags in the html with

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do like that;

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="your/file/address/fileName.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: better to place before closing `</body>` tag ^^

Comment: also, there's use of single quotes and double quotes within the same line - stick to one for practices sake :)

Comment: The script in the question depends on appearing *after* the paragraph in the DOM, so moving it to the head as you demonstrate here will break it.